# How long can a string be until it spills into the next word?

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, string, rlp

`string` is dynamic length storage.

I imagine a string of length (bytes length) 1, 2 or 3 is all the same length on storage, probably one word.

Which byte causes it to spill over into a second, third and fourth word?

---

I tried using strings like "123456789abcdef0" that repeated on and on. This is the data I came up with. I also tried splicing in emoji at the beginning or end of the string.

- Transaction cost /    Execution cost /    Length(bytes)
- 48302 26454   1
- 50222 26454   31
- **70389   46557   32**
- 90651 66627   33
- 92635 66627   64
- **112897  86697   65**
- 114881    86697   96
- **135143  106767  97**
- 137127    106767  128
- **157389  126837  129**

Test case:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;
contract StringGas {
    string[] words;
    function StringGas() public {
        words.push("BEGIN");
    }
    function addAWord(string _word) external {
        words.push(_word);
    }
}
```

I did it by hand. I'm sure somebody has a fancy Truffle way to do this. This is just data, maybe there is SOME input that breaks my experiment here.

Comment: Splitting in emoji?

Comment: "1234567890" > "(happy face)56(happy face)"

Comment: I still have no idea what you're referring to. Is (happy face) supposed to be equivalent to both 1234 and 7890 ?

Comment: Here is the [Solidity doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#bytes-and-string) that talks to this. Basically, a sting of up to 31 bytes stays in 1 word, 31 bytes for the string itself and 1 byte for the string length. Once the strings hits 32 bytes it takes 2 words, 1 word for the state slot, which stores the length, and 1 word for the string itself. At this point additional words are added each time the next 32 byte boundary is broken. The cost/length data in the question bares this out.

Answer (score 1):

A string contains a 1 word (32 byte) length, followed by its bytes packed right zero padded to the nearest 32 byte word. Keep in mind that utf-8 characters like emoji are multiple bytes long.

```
var ethers = require('ethers');

function getString(length) {
    var s = '';
    while (s.length < length) { s += '0'; }
    return s;
}

for (var l = 0; l < 5 * 32; l++) {
    var b = ethers.utils.AbiCoder.defaultCoder.encode(
        [ 'string' ],
        [ getString(l) ]
    );
    // Subtracting 2 for the 0x prefix (hex string)
    // Dividing by 2 since 2 nibbles per byte (hex string)
    // Subtracting 32 because the ABI includes a pointer
    console.log('length=' + l + ' => bytes=' + ((b.length - 2) / 2 - 32));
}
```

---

Which gives us (length is string length, bytes is storage bytes):

- length=0 => bytes=32
- length=1 => bytes=64
- length=2 => bytes=64
- ...
- length=32 => bytes=64
- length=33 => bytes=96
- ...
- length=64 => bytes=96
- length=65 => bytes=128
- ...
- length=96 => bytes=128
- length=97 => bytes=160
- ...
- length=128 => bytes=160
- length=129 => bytes=192

Comment: I think you are talking about ABI encoding/decoding, which is different from storage. The article [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 3 — The Hidden Costs of Arrays](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-the-hidden-costs-of-arrays-28e119f04a9b) explain how solidity strings and arrays are encoded in storage, ie strings less than 31 bytes in length uses 1 storage slot.